# Sharing multi-threaded code between standard C++ and OpenCL

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

I am trying to develop a C++ application that will have to run many calculations in parallel. The algorithms will be pretty large but they will be purely mathematical and on floating point integers. They should therefore work on the GPU using OpenCL. I would like the program to work on systems that do not support OpenCL but I would like for it to also be able to use the GPU for extra speed on systems that do.

My problem is that I do not want to have to maintain two sets of code (standard C++ probably using std::thread and OpenCL). I do realize that I will be able to share a lot of the actual code but the only obvious way to do so is to manually copy the shareable parts over between the files and that is really not something that I want to do for maintainability reasons and to prevent errors.

I would like to be able to use only one set of files. Is there any proper way to do this? Would OpenCL emulation be an option in a way?

PS. I know of the AMD OpenCL emulator but it seems to be only for development and also only for Windows. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL can use the CPU as a compute device, so OpenCL code can run on platforms without a GPU. However, the architectural differences between a GPU and a CPU will most likely require you to still maintain two code bases to get optimal performance in both situations.

Comment: I realize that OpenCL can run on a CPU but on older platforms and especially embedded devices tend to not have native OpenCL drivers available for it.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood, I assumed that OpenCL was still available on all platforms you were targeting, and it was just a GPU that was missing.

Comment: @Gerhman Unrelated, but do you have the ability to use MMX/SSE on the older platforms/embedded devices? If you want speed, it's definitely worth looking into.

Comment: @RyanP I am not sure if that will be an option. In terms of embedded I am referring partially to mobile applications including iOS, Android and Windows Phone ones.

Comment: This is a very wide spread of platforms and unfortunately I think it's unlikely that you will be able to target all of them with a single high-performance code base.

Comment: @Gerhman for the mobile phones, I'd look to see how easy/hard it would be to implement ARM's SIMD instructions (NEON)

Comment: @Aderstedt I am not looking at getting the absolute maximum performance. I would just like to easily run my code in parallel in all the available hardware. Something like C++ AMP would be perfect were it only more cross-platform.

Comment: @RyanP I will look into it but I would not really want to go into writing assembly for all my platforms if that is what you are implying.

Comment: @Gerhman Just a thought. On x86 you can use the intrinsic libraries to leverage SSE/AVX without writing assembly (granted it takes a little practice) or you can use BLAS libraries and the like that implement it for you. Never used Neon but with SSE I was able to speed up some of my image processing apps by ~3.5x (that is multithreaded SSE vs just multithreaded)

Comment: @Gerhman Coincidentally it looks like Android offers OpenMP support if you wanted a common code-base between x86 and your android apps, going to guess that iOS doesn't support it however, and I'm not sure about whatever other embedded devices you may be using.

Comment: @RyanP, I'll look into the special instructions and maybe they will help with performance but that won't really help with this question which relates to code sharing. I'm not sure if OpenMP will work on all my platforms but as far as I have it, it will also not help for GPGPU.